# htaccess redirect not working in same domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I want to redirect `https://xxx.xxxx.com/zzz` to `https://xxx.xxxx.com/zzz247`. I have tried this

```
Redirect 301 / https://xxx.xxxx.com/zzz247
```

So now when I try `https://xxx.xxxx.com/zzz` its take me into `https://xxx.xxxx.com/zzz247zzz247zzz247zzz247zzz247zzz247zzz247....`

How can I fix this issue? help please

**What is required**

I need enable only one URL which is `https://xxx.xxxx.com/zzz247` even user type `https://xxx.xxxx.com/zzz`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `Redirect` directive use `RedirectMatch` with regex support:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/zzz/?$ /zzz247
```

`Redirect` appends current URI into redirected URI and since you're matching `/` that will match anything and cause a redirect loop.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing.

---

Using `RewriteRule` you can do this:

```
RewriteRule ^zzz/?$ /zzz247? [L,NC,R=301]
```

`?` at the end of the target URI is for stripping any query string.

Comment: but now it take me into `https://xxx.xxxx.com/zzz247zzz247zzz247zzz247zzz247zzz247zzz247...` when i try `https://xxx.xxxx.com/zzz247`

Comment: helped and upvote. but still has a issue. please wait

Comment: It appends `?/zzz/` end of the URL. So when I try `https://xxx.xxxx.com/zzz` it goes to `https://xxx.xxxx.com/zzz247?/zzz/`. How can i remove that

Comment: Do you have other rules also? Make sure this is very first rule in your .htaccess and completely clear browser cache.

Comment: Yes there are some more rules like http to https, removing index.php etc etc. Yes I have put your code after `RewriteEngine On` this line

Comment: Use my suggested `RewriteRule` just below `RewriteEngine On` and clear browser cache.

Comment: yes tried your updated answer, cache cleared and trying in incognito mode. same issue its appending `?/zzz/` end of the URL

Comment: No, this rule is not appending any query string and in fact `?` in the end is stripping any query string. Is `zzz247` a directory by any chance. If not, paste your full .htaccess in question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127534/discussion-between-rejoanul-alam-and-anubhava).